# Using emoticon font in chrome

Tags: html, ios, css, google-chrome, emoticons

I've been looking around for a way to display emoticons in Chrome for a webpage I'm making. I found this link: github.com/MorbZ/OpenSansEmoji which provides an .odf file. I was hoping that font would work, so I dropped that file in with my other files. I tried to define a custom font and then use the emojis, but it didn't work. Any ideas, or suggestions for other working fonts/methods? Code:
HTML:

```
var titleDiv=document.createElement("div")
titleDiv.className="titleBox"
var postTitle=document.createElement("p")
postTitle.innerHTML=shout.get("postName");
postTitle.id="postName";
postTitle.style="font-family: EmojiFont";
titleDiv.appendChild(postTitle)
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'EmojiFont';
    src: url("OpenSansEmoji.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

Comment: Did you produce an .otf file from the .odt file? How? Does the font work for a simple static HTML file? Do you actually add the created `div` element to the document? Does the file get loaded when you check this in the browser’s network log?

Comment: I figured it out. You can use Twitter's open source emoji converter: https://github.com/twitter/twemoji